# Trying to skip recasting causes a race condition in OpenCL

Tags: python, opencl, atomic, pyopencl

I'm just going to start with code, then explain.

Say I have the following host code:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

host_arr = np.zeros(1,dtype=np.uint8)
host_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx,cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR,hostbuf=host_arr)

with open("kernel.cl","r") as knl_file:
    knl = cl.Program(ctx,knl_file.read()).build()

knl.run(queue,(255,),None,host_buf)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue,host_arr,host_buf)

print (host_arr)

queue.finish()
```

and "kernel.cl" contains the following:

```
__kernel void run (__global uchar *arr) {
atomic_inc(&arr[0]);
}
```

NOTE: This kernel does not currently work, I'm just showing what I want the kernel to be like.

Obviously, this will not work, as you cannot atomically increment using the uchar datatype. However, I would like to use either the uchar datatype or the uint8 datatype. Is there anything I can do so that the output of this code is "[255]"?

Basic explanation of the expected result: I want multiple workers of the kernel to be able to add a value to the same index of an array at once, but I want it to be in the uint8 or uchar datatype, so I can avoid recasting.

Answer (score 0):

If device does not have the capability of atomic increment on single byte targets, then it may never do it for every 3 bytes after each 4-byte-aligned byte. Alignment condition could stop it working even if you cast it to a wider (such as int) type.

In your example, you are using zeroth element which should be already aligned but it may or may not work for `arr[1]`, `arr[2]` and `arr[3]` depending on capabilities of the GPU. Try it, if it doesn't even normally load&store an integer on casted `arr[1]`, it will also not work for the atomic functions. Also try to do same only on `arr[4], arr[8], ... arr[k*4]`, they should work.

Why are you trying to skip recasting? If only for readability, why not use an int pointer instead of char? As long as kernel doesn't overflow the backing buffer of arr, it should work like this:

```
__kernel void run (__global int *arr) {
     atomic_inc(&arr[0]); // every k-th item maps to 4*k in original char buf
}
```

But, if you want to use only `char*` type arr efficiently in a later kernel, then, after the first kernel (using int) completes, do a "stream compaction" kernel which compresses every 4th item into a contiguous chunk of char array (values will not surpass 255 right?).

I think the compaction kernel would look something like a "gather" kernel. Launch only single work-group (i.e. only 256 threads) to process whole array like this:

```
__kernel void compaction (__global char* arr) {
     for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
     {
         char tmp = arr[(get_global_id(0)+i*256)*4];

         // only required for the first 256 data
         // there should be no collision after that
         // so no barrier call needed after that (did not test)
         if(i==0)
             barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
         arr[get_global_id(0)+i*256]=tmp;
     }
}
```